# load JavaScript on WebViewClient (onPageStarted e onPageFinished)

Tags: android, webview

I have a subclass called WebPageReader that extend the ViewPager. For each page I load a WebView. For each instance I load the webview via `loadDataWithBaseURL()` an html which is in the internal directory app. Everything is working beauty but I have some javascripts that are not working very well. These javascripts open a text box with detailed information about a word when it receives a touch and fires a javascript via `click ()`.

The `file.js` content I extract for a `mJavaScriptFile` variable and apply in the event `OnPageStarted and OnPageFinished with view.loadUrl ("javascript:" + mJavaScriptFile)`.

The problem is that when the webview loads the html javascript execution fails and sometimes works. Have only put in OnPageFinished but still keeps crashing sometimes works.

Can I help-me someone? What I missing?

Comment: Thanks Amit by edit! Now it more clean!